# Is there an out of the box way to put mailto: links on the emails in the contact search results?

Tags: search-results

I customized the contact search result view by using a profile (without the state, but with phone and email) and made this profile the default view.
I am looking for a way to make the emails clickable (mailto) so my coworkers can just click this and use their mailclient to do a straight forward mail. (either that or a mail button, any solution would be appreciated.

tia

Answer (score 1):

Yes, its possible using hook_civicrm_searchColumns to rewrite the email row to include mailto